# API Rest Spring boot

Tags: java, api, spring-boot, rest

Estou desenvolvendo uma API para cadastrar clientes utilizando Rest e spring, consigo já adicionar clientes e pesquisar por Id, porem também gostaria de conseguir pesquisar por nome e não estou conseguindo, alguém saberia me dizer como posso implementar isso? Muito obrigado

ClienteRepository:

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import com.api.resources.Cliente;

@Repository
public interface ClienteRepository extends JpaRepository<Cliente, Integer>{
}
```

ClienteResource:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.api.repository.ClienteRepository;
import com.api.resources.Cliente;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(path="/clientes")
public class ClienteResource{
    
    private ClienteRepository clienteRepository;

    public ClienteResource(ClienteRepository clienteRepository){
        super();
        this.clienteRepository = clienteRepository;
    }

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Cliente> save(@RequestBody Cliente cliente){
        clienteRepository.save(cliente);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(cliente, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<Cliente>> getAll(){
        List<Cliente> clientes = new ArrayList<>();
        clientes = clienteRepository.findAll();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(clientes, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    
    @GetMapping(path="/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Optional<Cliente>> getById(@PathVariable Integer id){
        Optional<Cliente> cliente;
        try{
            cliente = clienteRepository.findById(id);
            return new ResponseEntity<Optional<Cliente>>(cliente, HttpStatus.OK);
        }catch (NoSuchElementException nsee){
            return new ResponseEntity<Optional<Cliente>>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
    }
    
    @DeleteMapping(path="/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Optional<Cliente>> deleteById(@PathVariable Integer id){
    try{
        clienteRepository.deleteById(id);
        return new ResponseEntity<Optional<Cliente>>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }catch (NoSuchElementException nsee){
        return new ResponseEntity<Optional<Cliente>>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}

@PutMapping(value="/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<Cliente> update(@PathVariable Integer id, @RequestBody Cliente novoCliente){
    return clienteRepository.findById(id)
            .map(cliente -> {
                cliente.setNome(novoCliente.getNome());
                Cliente clienteUpdated = clienteRepository.save(cliente);
                return ResponseEntity.ok().body(clienteUpdated);
            }).orElse(ResponseEntity.notFound().build());
}
}
```

Cliente:

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Cliente {


    @GeneratedValue
    @Id
    private int id;
    
    @Column(name = "nome")
    private String nome;
    
    @Column(name = "sexo")
    private String sexo;
    
    @Column (name = "datanascimento")
    private Integer datanascimento;
    
    
    public Cliente(String nome, String sexo, Integer datanascimento) {
        super();
        this.nome = nome;
        this.sexo = sexo;
        this.datanascimento = datanascimento;
    }
    
    public Cliente() {
        
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getSexo() {
        return sexo;
    }

    public void setSexo(String sexo) {
        this.sexo = sexo;
    }

    public Integer getDatanascimento() {
        return datanascimento;
    }

    public void setDatanascimento(Integer datanascimento) {
        this.datanascimento = datanascimento;
    }

    
    
}
```

Comment: É só seguir a mesma lógica da sua busca por Id. A questão é que me parece que você copiou boa parte dessa estrutura de código e não tá entendendo realmente o que acontece aí. Sugiro você dar uma olhada como funciona a construção de métodos `findBy` pelo Spring Data: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation

Answer (score 0):

**ClienteRepository.java**

```
@Repository
public interface ClienteRepository extends JpaRepository<Cliente, Integer> {
    
    List<Cliente> findByNome(String nome);
    
}
```

**ClienteResource.java**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/clientes")
public class ClienteResource {

    @Autowired
    private ClienteRepository clienteRepository;

    // outros métodos e construtores omitidos para ser breve

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<Cliente>> getAll(@RequestParam("nome") String nome) {
        List<Cliente> clientes = new ArrayList<>();
        if(nome == null) {
            clientes = clienteRepository.findAll();
        } else {
            clientes = clienteRepository.findByNome(nome);
        }
        
        return ResponseEntity.ok(clientes);
    }
}
```

Uma requisição para `/clientes?nome=Jorge` buscaria todos os clientes de nome 'Jorge'. Se quiser buscar por partes do nome, altere o método de `findByNome` para `findByNomeLike`.

O Spring Data tem um mecanismo capaz de definir uma query derivando do nome de um método dentro de um repositório, sem que você precise escrever `JPQL` ou alguma `Native Query` para isso (claro que isso não cobre todos os casos de uso).

O método `findByNome` é entendido pelo query builder do Spring, então sofre um parse e gera um resultado de query a ser executada na base. A query gerada é algo como:

```
SELECT c FROM Cliente AS c WHERE c.nome = :nome
```